# jenkins clone and zip repository

Tags: jenkins

i'm currently new to jenkins and i'm trying clone the repo and create a zip and finally upload to s3.

But i'm currently stuck with zip as the default folder location of clone file is `/var/lib/jenkins/<project-view>`

```
def getFilename() {
  char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(3)
  Random random = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
      sb.append(c);
  }
  String randomString = sb.toString();
  def now = new Date().format("yyyyMMdd")
  String output = now + randomString
  return output
}

pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    FILENAME = getFilename()
  }
    
  stages {
    stage("Zip"){
      steps{
        script{
          echo "Creating zip archive ${env.FILENAME}.zip"
          zip archive: true, dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: "${env.FILENAME}.zip"
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${env.FILENAME}.zip", fingerprint: true
        }
      }
    }
        
    stage('Upload to AWS') {
      steps {
        withAWS(region:'eu-west-2',credentials:'7b42d7b6-f11b-41b6-8c14-61dafbd256c7') {
          sh 'echo "Uploading content with AWS creds"'
          s3Upload(pathStyleAccessEnabled: true, payloadSigningEnabled: true, file: "${env.FILENAME}.zip", bucket:'elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-246342104703')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i tried with providing specific dir to zip `/var/lib/jenkins/<project-view>`, but was unable to zip the file, any help for this newbie here . thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not very clear on the problem. Do you get an error message when the Zip stage fails? Is the problem that the directory to be zipped is not found, or that when you try to upload to S3, the zip is missing?

Comment: zipped file not found when trying to upload to s3, ```Upload failed due to missing source file```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is that the S3 command is being executed in a different place from where the zip file is located. Try adding this:

```
dir('location to your zip') {
```

after `steps {`. This will ensure that the `withAWS` command runs in the same directory as your zip file, and it should be able to find the zip.